# pass props to component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
const { component, setComponent } = useState();
setComponent(MyComponent) // < how to pass props here?
```

later on in do something like

```
const Component = () => component;
<Component />
```

I dosen´t make much sense here in this scenario but just wanted to illustrate how I need to pass props

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
const [component, setComponent] = useState(null);
setComponent(<MyComponent prop1="property"/>)
```

Just pass a function to state, that returns component.

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
setComponent(MyComponent({prop1: 'value}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
const { component, setComponent } = useState();
setComponent(<MyComponent prop={$prop} {...props}/>)
```